# Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end{document}

Tags: pdftex

I have no idea how to fix this - it worked perfectly fine before I rebooted my PC! Help please!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%--!GLOBAL CONTROLS!--
%Packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{amsmath}       % additional math environments
\usepackage{graphicx}      % graphics import from external files 
\usepackage{epstopdf}      % automates .eps to .pdf conversion 
\usepackage{booktabs}      % table typesetting additions
\usepackage{siunitx}       % number and units formatting
\usepackage{caption}       % customisation of captions
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage[top=4cm, bottom=2cm, outer=3cm, inner=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}

% set up caption options
\captionsetup{format=hang,width=0.85\textwidth,labelfont=bf}

% global options for siunitx
\sisetup{seperr,repeatunits=false,per=frac}   
%-----------------------------------------------------------------+-+-+-

\backgroundsetup{
    placement=center,
    nodeanchor=center,
    position={\paperwidth-5.29in,-4.5in}, %Set up for A4 measurements in px
    scale=1,
    color=black,
    opacity=0.25,
    angle=0,
    contents={%
        \vspace{0}
        \hspace{0}
        \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,]{Group5aBG.png}
    }%
}

\title{Pendulum Dynamics Investigation}
\author{\underline{Group 5a} \\ \\ Libby Warren \\ Lilly Damany-Pearce \\ Maria Nicanor \\ Freddie Goodman \\ Harry McWilliam \\ Elliott Browse-Phillips}
\date{6th March 2017}

\begin{document}

    \BgThispage

    \maketitle

    \section*{Abstract}
    1. Avoid notation if possible. Notation makes it really hard to search electronically. \\
    2. Put the subject in context, e.g., "In a recent paper, T. Lehrer introduced the concept of left-bifurcled rectangles. He conjectured no such rectangles exist when the number of bifurcles nn is odd." \\
    3. State your results, in non-technical language, if possible. "In this paper we show the existence of left-bifurcled rectangles for all prime nn." \\
    4. Mention a technique, if there is a new one: "Our methods involve analytic and algebraic topology of locally euclidean metrizations of infinitely differentiable Riemannian manifolds". \\
    5. Never, ever, ever, cite papers in the bibliography by giving citation numbers; the abstract is an independent entity that should stand on its own. 

    With focus to Newtonian dynamics, this investigation calls us to apply one of the most fundamental: Newton’s second law, $F = ma$. This was used extensively to model the dynamical system of a simple pendulum. \par
    The model was set to feature a point particle of mass $m$, suspended from a pivoting fixed point, by a string of fixed length $l$, such that the pendulum was free to swing freely under the action of gravity, with gravitational acceleration $g \simeq 9.81 m s ^{-2}$ \par

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. Thank you for providing the Minimal Working Example. Your problem is fixed by adding `pt` after the number given for `vspace` and `hspace` in `\backgroundsetup`.

Comment: this is a syntax error the file would never have worked, this is not a change to the system. Why are you loading `ae` or `pslatex`  also `epstopdf`  is not needed.

Answer (score 10):

The error is

```
    \vspace{0}
    \hspace{0}
```

both hspace and vspace need units you could use

```
    \vspace{0pt}
    \hspace{0pt}
```

or more simply just delete these lines.

Comment: Is it possible to silence such warnings? (Via scripting, not by shell)

Comment: @DanielBandeira they are not warnings they are essentially fatal syntax errors. After such an error, if you choose to scroll past the error the PDF is at best usable for debugging. Certainly not usable as a document.

Comment: So if I want to create a simple math function to work with float numbers, my macros need to put a "pt" after each number, right?. Is unit pt preferable to do such work?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @DanielBandeira sorry the site doesn't work to ask  questions as comments on old answers.  I would not use dimen arithmetic (it is fixed point not float and not that accurate) use `\fpeval` (built in to the latex-dev release or via the `xfp` package)